# How to get the value of a variable during runtime with LLVM pass?

Tags: runtime, llvm, instrumentation

For example, I need to get the value of **length** during **runtime**, how should I write the LLVM pass to instrument the target program?

```
...
memcpy(a, b, length);
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Loop over the instructions and if one is a call to memcpy, get operand 3. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Sure, I can get the variable with I->getArgOperand(2). And I need to store it in somewhere, say **ptr**. How should I write the pass? I am not very familiar with LLVM instrumentation. Thanks! @arnt